# Turtlebot unable to check laptop battery/BAT0/state

Tags: ros, battery, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My laptop (Thinkpad X120e) reports its battery status in proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/ folder (which does have the status file), but NOT in BAT0 that turtlebot expects. How do I either change the Ubuntu environment to use BAT0 or change the minimal.launch script to look in the BAT1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30631/turtlebot-unable-to-check-laptop-battery/bat0/state/) by [RobotRoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/1992/robotross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem.  Since the EeePC 1215N was discontinued, the Turtlebot now ships from I Heart Robotics with a Lenovo ThinkPad X130e.  This laptop's battery shows up in /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1, not BAT0 as is hardcoded into ROS electric's laptop_battery.py.  Also, the battery's capacity and charge state is reported in mW instead of mA, so just swapping BAT0 to BAT1 in the script doesn't fix it.

I've uploaded an updated version of electric's laptop_battery.py that should fix both of these problems:
[http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~olawlor/2012/laptop_battery.py](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/%7Eolawlor/2012/laptop_battery.py)

I use a shell glob to find BAT*, and recognize either mW or mA for battery capacity. This should work with both EeePC and ThinkPad based turtlebots, but I only have the ThinkPad to test with. To use the new script, from your turtlebot:

1. wget [http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~olawlor/2012/laptop_battery.py](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/%7Eolawlor/2012/laptop_battery.py)
2. sudo cp laptop_battery.py /opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot/turtlebot_node/scripts/laptop_battery.py
3. sudo rosmake turtlebot_node
4. sudo service turtlebot restart

---

Originally posted by [Dr. Orion Lawlor](https://answers.ros.org/users/2118/dr.-orion-lawlor/) with karma: 56 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-04-07**:
http://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/ticket/134

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-04-07**:
Thanks for the help! I have patchified things and made some adjustments. Please post feedback on the patch to the ticket.